# Gatsby proxy to multiple backends with same prefix

Tags: reactjs, gatsby

I have two different API backends running on ports `8080` and `9090`. I am developing frontend with gatsby.
Is it possible to proxy `/api/specific-path` to one backend (example to `9090`) and all other `/api` calls to the other backend (`8080`)?

Tried this in `gatsby-config.js`, but all `/api` requests are going to `8080`:

```js
  proxy: [
    {
      prefix: "/api",
      url: "http://localhost:8080",
    },
    {
      prefix: "/api/specific-path",
      url: "http://localhost:9090",
    },
  ],
```

Perhaps using nginx as reverse proxy for backends, and sorting requests there would solve the problem, but ideally I would like to avoid setting up extra services for local development.

Comment: Switching the order of the proxies might do the trick.

Comment: Unfortunately, it does not

Comment: @DanielGeffen You are correct. My bad. It has to be in the first position. I was testing with `/api/specific-path/subpath` in proxy rules which was not working. It has to be `/api/subpath`, only prefix without full path.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're looking to do this during **development only** then yes, you can use express middleware to set up multiple path-based proxies. In production, Gatsby does not run server-side and cannot configure response headers or proxy settings.

In `gatsby-config.js`:

```js
const proxy = require("http-proxy-middleware")

module.exports = {
  plugins: [],

  developMiddleware: app => {
    app.use(
      "/api/specific-path",
      proxy({
        target: "http://localhost:9090",
        pathRewrite: {
          "/api/specific-path": "", // optionally remove the path prefix from the proxied request
        },
      })
    )

    app.use(
      "/api/",
      proxy({
        target: "http://localhost:8080",
        pathRewrite: {
          "/api/": "",
        },
      })
    )
  },
}
```

Note that `http-proxy-middleware` is included as part of Gatsby (webpack-dev-server, really) so you don't *have to* to add it to your dev dependencies unless you care about the version you're using for some reason.